# finding directory size on linux with du reports errors when files are deleted during command

Tags: linux, du

I'm trying to find out the directory size of a folder to determine if a user has rights to keep writing to the folder (i.e. they are within the given limits I've imposed).

I'm doing:

```
du -sb <path>
```

which is fine and all, but the problem is if whilst this is being executed, another user deletes something from that directory then **`du`** chucks a bunch of **`Cannot find file`** errors to the console.

Is there any way of handling this or at least stopping du chucking errors?

Thanks

Comment: `du -sb 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: yes that will work I think :)